# MethodImpl(32) needed in .NET 4?

Tags: c#

I'm updating an old WinForms project targeting .NET 1.0, now .NET 4.

It was not written by me, and as my first framework was 2.0, it holds some code unfamiliar to me.

For example, it has a lot of code blocks like this:

```cs
internal virtual Label someLabel
{
    get
    {
        return this._someLabel;
    }
    [MethodImpl(32)]
    set
    {
        this._someLabel == null;
        this._someLabel = value;
        this._someLabel == null;
    }
}
```

One question:

1. What is the purpose of the two lines will *null* that don't even compile?

Can I just replace it with:

```cs
internal virtual Label someLabel
{
    get
    {
        return this._someLabel;
    }
    set
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    {
        this._someLabel = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: `32` is `MethodImplOptions.Synchronized` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions?view=netframework-4.8). I -think- its the same as `lock (this) { this._someLabel = value; }`.

Comment: That's not encouraging.  Sure looks like you'll need to shop for a better decompiler.  Technically it could have been auto-generated with a wonky approach to generating a memory barrier.  This kind of code can never run correctly on a worker thread since Label is fundamentally thread-unsafe, so sure, whack it like that.

Comment: do you have the source code, or ist that decompiled?

Comment: @HansPassant: It's _Telerik JustDecompile_. I've edited the question implementing the previous comments.

Comment: Ditch it, use ILSpy or Reflector.  Spend the money.

Comment: @HansPassant: OK, I'm listening. So the _null_ could be generated by the decompiler?

Comment: The 32 is very lame.  Not generating a proper C# statement is very lame.  The null could actually be valid.  The language that was originally used to write the program is fairly mysterious, maybe J#.

Comment: You will (likely) get different results from different decompilers.  I second the use of ILSpy.

Comment: @Gustav you could also give a try with https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/ it's free

Comment: @gsharp et al: Thanks. I'll try another decompiler and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ILSpy** did it:

```cs
internal virtual Label someLabel
{
    get
    {
        return _someLabel;
    }
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    set
    {
        if (_someLabel != null)
        {
        }
        _someLabel = value;
        if (_someLabel == null)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Still a little twisted, but it compiles.

*Thanks for the input!*